# How to display checkboxes depending on number selected in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I display a set of checkboxes depending on the item that has been selected in a drop-down list?

I got a drop-down list that contains 'number of seats'. I need to see a list of checkboxes of seats that corresponding to the number of seats that selected.

I have a list of seats in the database but i need them to be displayed when user select a number in selected option

Right now when i load the page I got an error that "noSeat" variable is not defined

My controller

```
class Timetable extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Queries');
        $seats = $this->Queries->getSeats($noSeats);
        $template['page'] = "InsertMultipleRecords/insertMultipleRecords";
        $template['page_title'] = "BUS SCHEDULE";
        //$this->load->view('template', $template);

        $this->load->view('InsertMultipleRecords/insertMultipleRecords', ['seats'=>$seats]);
    }
```

My Model

```
public function getSeats(){
{
    $query = $this->db->from('seat')->where('noSeats', $noSeats)->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }  
}
}
```

My view

```
<body>
<div style="margin-bottom:2% !important;"> 
<?php echo form_open('Timetable/message'); ?>
<fieldset >     
     <h1>JOURNEY SCHEDULE</h1>     
     <br/>
     <div>
     <div>

<div >
<select  name="noSeats" class="form-control" placeholder="Seats">
                    <option value="">Seats</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="49">49</option>
                    <option value="51">51</option>
                    <option value="53">53</option>
                    <option value="56">56</option>
                    <option value="57">57</option>
                    <option value="61">61</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


                  <div >
                   <br/>
                   <input id="from-datepicker" class="form-control" type="text" name="bookingDate" placeholder="Date of Journey"></>
                </div>
                <div >

              </div>
                  <br/>
               <div>                   
                   <input id="mytextbox" class="form-control" type="text" name="busNumber" placeholder="T 618 CCG"></>
                </div>

                <br/>

                <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <?php echo form_error('busNumber', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                <?php echo form_error('bookingDate', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php echo form_error('seatId', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                 <table cellspacing="50"  align="center">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                       <th> <input type="button" id="toggle" value="All" onClick="do_this()"/></th>
                       <th>Seat</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php if(count ($seats)):?>
                    <?php foreach ($seats as $seat):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" value=<?php echo $seat->seatNumber;?>></td>
                        <td><?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

                    <?php else:?>
                    <td>No Records Founds!</td>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                  <br/>

                     <div>
                <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Set Schedule', 'class'=>'btn btn-info pull-center']); ?>
                </div>
                  </fieldset>

              <?php echo form_close(); ?>
              </div>    
              </body>
```

My Html page

[image]

But on top of that table, there is the following error

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: noSeats

Filename: controllers/Timetable.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:

File: /home/n17ljw1lcuti/public_html/ticketing/core/admin/application/controllers/Timetable.php
Line: 10
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/n17ljw1lcuti/public_html/ticketing/core/admin/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Also

```
  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: noSeats

Filename: controllers/Timetable.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:

File: /home/n17ljw1lcuti/public_html/ticketing/core/admin/application/controllers/Timetable.php
Line: 10
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/n17ljw1lcuti/public_html/ticketing/core/admin/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

A table that is fetched to display checkboxes of seats depending on seats selected

[image]

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Either replace `$this->Queries->getSeats($noSeats);` with `$this->Queries->getSeats();` or define `$noSeats` variable  in your `index` method

Comment: @LajosArpad  line  `$seats = $this->Queries->getSeats($noSeats);` on controller and line `$query = $this->db->from('seat')->where('noSeats', $noSeats)->get();` on model

Comment: I want a list of checkboxes to display depending on number of seats selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you attempt to use a variable called `$noSeats`, without initializing it. You need to initialize it in order to be able to use it. For example:

```
$noSeats = 45;
$seats = $this->Queries->getSeats($noSeats);
```

or

```
$noSeats = 45;
$query = $this->db->from('seat')->where('noSeats', $noSeats)->get();
```

Comment: @Coeng your question was about an error regarding a variable which was tried to be used, but was not initialized. You need to initialize it. I do not know how you want to initialize it, so, if it must be such a selected value, then you will need to use the corresponding value which should be in the post variables. However, I do not see your form tag in the HTML.